# Copyright symbol in postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I have an oracle function that takes strings and concatenates them adding the copyright symbol as the seperator between them. so 'hi' and 'hello' becomes `'hi©hello'` In oracle in defining the function CHR(49833) is used as seperator which returns the copy right symbol. How do I do it in postgres? If I `select chr(49833)` in postgres it returns this character: "슩".

Comment: Any reason you can't just do `'hi' || '©' || 'hello'`?

Comment: In my actual work issue, this symbol is a parameter to the function in Oracle that I have to convert to postgres. So any strings passed use this parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to find out:

```
SELECT g
FROM generate_series(1, 10000) g
WHERE CHR(g) = '©'
```

result: 169

And `SELECT CHR(169)` returns `©`

Comment: Very very excellent!! It completely solved my problem. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Re why it's 169: For UTF-8, the argument is a [Unicode code point number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), and for non-UTF-8, non-ASCII values are illegal.

Comment: `CHR()` is sensitive to your database encoding; if you want something portable, you can use a [Unicode escape sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE), e.g. `SELECT U&'\00A9'`